# Setting the weight of LinearView within code

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to replicate the layout-weight parameter that you can set in XML within the onCreate method of my class I am creating. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set linearlayout params:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html